# Compilation working on my Mac but not on the cluster (Linux)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17, cluster-computing, compile-time

I have a library in c++17 which compiles on my Mac, but not the cluster of my university (Linux).

My compiler is:

Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)

The cluster compiler is:

g++ (Spack GCC) 9.2.0

Also a colleague of mine installed the library and compiled it with success on its machine (always a Mac).

I have tried to reduce everything to the main (I guess) error, putting everything in the code below.

Here is the error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class TensorBase<double, std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, 0> >'
  116 |  class Matrix<Real,1,1,NonZeroRow_>: public TensorBase<Real, std::make_index_sequence<1>>
```

Below I put the code. I basically have a `BaseTensor` class from which a class `Matrix` inherits. Of such a class I have also a specialisation.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>  


    using Integer=long;
    using Real=double;



    template <typename T, std::size_t>
    using getTypeSequence = T;



    template <typename, typename>
    class TensorBase;

    template <typename T, Integer ... Is>
    class TensorBase<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
    {
    protected:
        std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> values{};
        static const std::size_t Size = sizeof...(Is);

    public:
        constexpr TensorBase (getTypeSequence<T, Is> ... vals)
        : values{{vals...}}
        {}

        constexpr TensorBase (std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> const & a)
        : values{a}
        {}

        constexpr TensorBase (std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> && a)
        : values{std::move(a)}
        {}

        // TensorBase(std::initializer_list<T> a)
        // {
        //     assert(a.size() == Size);
        //     std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(values));
        // }
 
        constexpr TensorBase () = default;

        ~TensorBase() = default;

        constexpr TensorBase (TensorBase const &) = default;
        constexpr TensorBase (TensorBase &&) = default;

        constexpr TensorBase & operator= (TensorBase const &) = default;
        constexpr TensorBase & operator= (TensorBase &&) = default;
    };


    template<typename T, Integer Rows_, Integer Cols_,Integer NonZeroRow_=-1>
    class Matrix: public TensorBase<T, std::make_index_sequence<Rows_*Cols_>> 
    {
    public:
        static constexpr Integer Rows=Rows_;
        static constexpr Integer Cols=Cols_;
        using type= Matrix<T,Rows,Cols>;
        using subtype=T;
        using MB = TensorBase<T, std::make_index_sequence<Rows*Cols>>;
        using MB::MB;
        using MB::values;
        static constexpr Integer NonZeroRow=NonZeroRow_;
        inline constexpr static Integer rows() { return Rows; }
        inline constexpr static Integer cols() { return Cols; }
        inline constexpr std::array<T,Rows*Cols> &operator()()
        {
            return values;
        }

        inline constexpr const std::array<T,Rows*Cols> &operator()()const
        {
            return values;
        }
        // access matrix direclty by using I*Col+J index
        inline constexpr T &operator()(const Integer i)
        {
            assert(i < Rows*Cols);
            return values[i];
        }

        inline constexpr const T &operator()(const Integer i)const
        {
            assert(i < Rows*Cols);
            return values[i];
        }

        inline constexpr T &operator()(const Integer i, const Integer j)
        {
            assert(i < Rows);
            assert(j < Cols);
            return values[i*cols() + j];
        }

        inline constexpr const T &operator()(const Integer i, const Integer j) const
        {
            assert(i < Rows);
            assert(j < Cols);
            return values[i*cols() + j];
        }
    };





    template<Integer NonZeroRow_>
    class Matrix<Real,1,1,NonZeroRow_>: public TensorBase<Real, std::make_index_sequence<1>> 
    {
    public:
        static constexpr Integer Rows=1;
        static constexpr Integer Cols=1;
        using T= Real;
        using type= Matrix<T,Rows,Cols>;
        using subtype=T;
        using MB = TensorBase<T, std::make_index_sequence<Rows*Cols>>;
        using MB::MB;
        using MB::values;
        static constexpr Integer NonZeroRow=NonZeroRow_;
        inline constexpr static Integer rows() { return Rows; }
        inline constexpr static Integer cols() { return Cols; }

        inline constexpr std::array<T,Rows*Cols> &operator()()
        {
            return values;
        }

        inline constexpr const std::array<T,Rows*Cols> &operator()()const
        {
            return values;
        }

        inline constexpr T &operator[](const Integer i)
        {
            assert(i < Rows);
            return values[i];
        }

        inline constexpr T &operator[](const Integer i)const
        {
            assert(i < Rows);
            return values[i];
        }


        // access matrix direclty by using I*Col+J index
        inline constexpr T &operator()(const Integer i)
        {
            assert(i < Rows*Cols);
            return values[i];
        }

        inline constexpr const T &operator()(const Integer i)const
        {
            assert(i < Rows*Cols);
            return values[i];
        }

        inline constexpr T &operator()(const Integer i, const Integer j)
        {
            assert(i < Rows);
            assert(j < Cols);
            return values[i*cols() + j];
        }

        inline constexpr const T &operator()(const Integer i, const Integer j) const
        {
            assert(i < Rows);
            assert(j < Cols);
            return values[i*cols() + j];
        }


    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        constexpr Matrix<Real,1,1> mat{1.0};


    std::cout<<"it works"<<std::endl;
    static_assert(mat(0,0)==1.0);



    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see in your code explicit #include <utility> where all related sequence types are defined. Probably one compiler has this include implicitly, the second one does not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to include also that, but it does not work either.

Comment: I think the incomplete type error is because the primary template for TensorBase is getting selected instead of the specialization. I made a smaller example that shows gcc select the primary template in a similar scenario https://godbolt.org/z/4YZkCU I think gcc is wrong to select the primary template but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `integer_sequence<Integer, Is...>` instead of `index_sequence<Is...>` and adding const to the return of `operator[]` in `Matrix<Real,1,1,NonZeroRow_>` fixed the build error for me in gcc 10.1.  I dont really know why using integer sequence instead fixes the problem, but besides fixing the build error the behavior should be equivalent in this case.

here is the version that compiles after the edits that i made https://godbolt.org/z/dKHLDB

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>  


using Integer=long;
using Real=double;



template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getTypeSequence = T;



template <typename, typename>
class TensorBase;

template <typename T, Integer ... Is>
class TensorBase<T, std::integer_sequence<Integer, Is...>>
{
protected:
    std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> values{};
    static const std::size_t Size = sizeof...(Is);

public:
    constexpr TensorBase (getTypeSequence<T, Is> ... vals)
    : values{{vals...}}
    {}

    constexpr TensorBase (std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> const & a)
    : values{a}
    {}

    constexpr TensorBase (std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> && a)
    : values{std::move(a)}
    {}

    // TensorBase(std::initializer_list<T> a)
    // {
    //     assert(a.size() == Size);
    //     std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(values));
    // }

    constexpr TensorBase () = default;

    ~TensorBase() = default;

    constexpr TensorBase (TensorBase const &) = default;
    constexpr TensorBase (TensorBase &&) = default;

    constexpr TensorBase & operator= (TensorBase const &) = default;
    constexpr TensorBase & operator= (TensorBase &&) = default;
};


template<typename T, Integer Rows_, Integer Cols_,Integer NonZeroRow_=-1>
class Matrix: public TensorBase<T, std::make_integer_sequence<Integer, Rows_*Cols_>> 
{
public:
    static constexpr Integer Rows=Rows_;
    static constexpr Integer Cols=Cols_;
    using type= Matrix<T,Rows,Cols>;
    using subtype=T;
    using MB = TensorBase<T, std::make_integer_sequence<Integer, Rows*Cols>>;
    using MB::MB;
    using MB::values;
    static constexpr Integer NonZeroRow=NonZeroRow_;
    inline constexpr static Integer rows() { return Rows; }
    inline constexpr static Integer cols() { return Cols; }
    inline constexpr std::array<T,Rows*Cols> &operator()()
    {
        return values;
    }

    inline constexpr const std::array<T,Rows*Cols> &operator()()const
    {
        return values;
    }
    // access matrix direclty by using I*Col+J index
    inline constexpr T &operator()(const Integer i)
    {
        assert(i < Rows*Cols);
        return values[i];
    }

    inline constexpr const T &operator()(const Integer i)const
    {
        assert(i < Rows*Cols);
        return values[i];
    }

    inline constexpr T &operator()(const Integer i, const Integer j)
    {
        assert(i < Rows);
        assert(j < Cols);
        return values[i*cols() + j];
    }

    inline constexpr const T &operator()(const Integer i, const Integer j) const
    {
        assert(i < Rows);
        assert(j < Cols);
        return values[i*cols() + j];
    }
};





template<Integer NonZeroRow_>
class Matrix<Real,1,1,NonZeroRow_>: public TensorBase<Real, std::make_integer_sequence<Integer,1>> 
{
public:
    static constexpr Integer Rows=1;
    static constexpr Integer Cols=1;
    using T= Real;
    using type= Matrix<T,Rows,Cols>;
    using subtype=T;
    using MB = TensorBase<T, std::make_integer_sequence<Integer,Rows*Cols>>;
    using MB::MB;
    using MB::values;
    static constexpr Integer NonZeroRow=NonZeroRow_;
    inline constexpr static Integer rows() { return Rows; }
    inline constexpr static Integer cols() { return Cols; }

    inline constexpr std::array<T,Rows*Cols> &operator()()
    {
        return values;
    }

    inline constexpr const std::array<T,Rows*Cols> &operator()()const
    {
        return values;
    }

    inline constexpr T &operator[](const Integer i)
    {
        assert(i < Rows);
        return values[i];
    }

    inline constexpr const T &operator[](const Integer i)const
    {
        assert(i < Rows);
        return values[i];
    }


    // access matrix direclty by using I*Col+J index
    inline constexpr T &operator()(const Integer i)
    {
        assert(i < Rows*Cols);
        return values[i];
    }

    inline constexpr const T &operator()(const Integer i)const
    {
        assert(i < Rows*Cols);
        return values[i];
    }

    inline constexpr T &operator()(const Integer i, const Integer j)
    {
        assert(i < Rows);
        assert(j < Cols);
        return values[i*cols() + j];
    }

    inline constexpr const T &operator()(const Integer i, const Integer j) const
    {
        assert(i < Rows);
        assert(j < Cols);
        return values[i*cols() + j];
    }


};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
constexpr Matrix<Real,1,1> mat{1.0};


std::cout<<"it works"<<std::endl;
static_assert(mat(0,0)==1.0);



return 0;
}
```

here are the specific changes:

before

```
template <typename T, Integer ... Is>
class TensorBase<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
```

after

```
template <typename T, Integer ... Is>
class TensorBase<T, std::integer_sequence<Integer, Is...>>
```

---

before

```
template<typename T, Integer Rows_, Integer Cols_,Integer NonZeroRow_=-1>
class Matrix: public TensorBase<T, std::make_index_sequence<Rows_*Cols_>>
```

after

```
template<typename T, Integer Rows_, Integer Cols_,Integer NonZeroRow_=-1>
class Matrix: public TensorBase<T, std::make_integer_sequence<Integer, Rows_*Cols_>>
```

---

before (in `Matrix`)

```
using MB = TensorBase<T, std::make_index_sequence<Rows*Cols>>;
```

after

```
using MB = TensorBase<T, std::make_integer_sequence<Integer, Rows*Cols>>;
```

---

before

```
template<Integer NonZeroRow_>
class Matrix<Real,1,1,NonZeroRow_>: public TensorBase<Real, std::make_index_sequence<1>>
```

after

```
template<Integer NonZeroRow_>
class Matrix<Real,1,1,NonZeroRow_>: public TensorBase<Real, std::make_integer_sequence<Integer, 1>>
```

---

before (in `Matrix<Real,1,1,NonZeroRow_>`)

```
using MB = TensorBase<T, std::make_index_sequence<Rows*Cols>>;
```

after

```
using MB = TensorBase<T, std::make_integer_sequence<Integer, Rows*Cols>>;
```

---

before (in `Matrix<Real,1,1,NonZeroRow_>`)

```
inline constexpr T &operator()(const Integer i)const
```

after

```
inline constexpr const T &operator()(const Integer i)const
```